# HTML input fields does not get focus when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem and I can't figure out what exactly is causing this behavior.  I cannot access my input fields and `textarea`s on my HTML form.

Unfortunately, the JS, HTML and CSS are very large, so I can't really post it all here.

Can anybody tell me what to look for when debugging this strange behavior?

**UPDATE**

If I move the cursor over the `input` field I can see the text cursor, but when I click it the field does not get the focus.  I can access the field via pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and if I right click on it and then click on the field I also get the focus for it.

...and nope, they don't have the `disabled` or `readonly` attributes ;-)

Comment: Sounds like you have a focus/blur thing going. Can you look for blur in the code?

Comment: can you view the generated source and just copy out one instance of a text field that is not working properly... it is extremely difficult to diagnose the problem without see anything... what plug-ins are you running ... turn off all your plug-ins disable javascript see if you are still having problem

Comment: For `select2` in `bootstrap` `modal` related issue see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> when i click it the field does not get the focus. i can access the field via pressing the "tab-key"

It sounds like you've cancelled the default action for the *mousedown* event.  Search through your HTML and JS for *onmousedown* handlers and look for a line that reads.

```
return false;
```

This line may be stopping you from focusing by clicking.

---

Re: your comment, I'm assuming you can't edit the code that adds this handler?  If you can, the simplest solution is to just remove the `return false;` statement.

> is there a way to just add functionality to the event-trigger by not overwriting it?

That depends on how the handler is attached.  If it's attached using the traditional registration method, e.g. *element.onmousedown*, then you could create a wrapper for it:

```
var oldFunc = element.onmousedown;
element.onmousedown = function (evt) {
    oldFunc.call(this, evt || window.event);
}
```

Since this "wrapper" doesn't return *false*, it will not cancel the default action (focusing) for the element.  If your event is attached using an advanced registration method, such as *addEventListener* or *attachEvent* then you could only remove the event handler using the function name/reference and reattach it with a wrapped function similar to the above.  If it's an anonymous function that's added and you can't get a reference to it, then the only solution would be to attach another event handler and focus the element manually using the *element.focus()* method.

Comment: Thanks.  This was my problem.  preventDefault() in mousedown.  Funny that it doesn't affect <button> elements.

Comment: its really weird that it dont effect buttons!!!  i have the same issue, and it only affects input fields of type text..

Comment: I tried to remove all attached events one by one, it seems like one of the focus-in event is culprit, So how to remove the focus in the event for particularly this input?

Answer (score 29):

I had this problem too. I used the `disableSelection()` method of jQuery UI on a parent DIV which contained my input fields. In Chrome the input fields were not affected but in Firefox the inputs (and textareas as well) did not get focused on clicking. The strange thing here was, that the click event on these inputs worked.

The solution was to remove the `disableSelection()` method for the parent DIV.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of time trying to recode my work thinking it was some other thing. I had this for .sortable and the end had the .disableSelection() attached.

Thats what I get for copy & pasting from the interwebs. :)

Answer (score 25):

Use the `onclick="this.select()"` attribute for the input tag.

Comment: This got the cursor into the text box, but I still couldn't type.

Comment: This worked for me, but it also selected any text already in there so I used this.focus() instead :)

Comment: Anyone know why this works? What's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 24):

I know this is a very old thread, but this just happened to me recently; took me a while to figure it out.

This same issue can be caused by putting 'input' elements inside of pair of 'label' tags.

In my case, I had intended to create a pair of 'div' tags but instead I accidently created a pair of 'label' tags, then inserted some text input fields 'input type="text"..' using DOM.

It displayed normally on the screen, but when I clicked on any of the text fields, the cursor kept jumping back to the first 'input' and really acting erratic.

Took me a while to figure this out because this behavior is subtle, and not at all what I would have expected from making this kind of mistake.

bsnider

Comment: This was my issue, specifically in Firefox. This is particularly problematic when using Zurb Foundation because the docs have `<input>` nested in `<label>`. Moving it out fixed my problem and the content rendered the same.

Comment: how did you fix your problem? I have input inside div and div is draggable, but input not, and when clicked, the cursors jumps to the end every time.

Comment: This happened to me even when the `<input>` element was nested inside only a single `<label>` tag. Very subtle behaviour indeed.

Comment: I had two input elements in the same label element. The second one couldn't get focus.

Answer (score 13):

I've been struggling with the same problem a while ago. I was using the jquery.layout plugin in a modal jquery-ui dialog and I couldn't access any of the fields in it.

It appeared to be a `z-index` problem (some `div` was over my input fields, so I couldn't click them). You should check it out and try changing the `z-index` value of your input fields.

Comment: Or make it non-transparent to see where it overlaps

Comment: Or use the property inspector from the developer toolbar.

Answer (score 8):

This happens sometimes when there are unbalanced `<label>` tags in the form.

Comment: What's an "unbalanced" `<label>` tag?  Do you mean invalid HTML syntax?

Comment: @GlennG unbalanced mean an open tag without a corresponding closing tag.

Comment: Singleton tags should be self-closed, e.g. `<br />`. A solo `<label>` tag makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, and in my case I found that the color of the font was the same color of the background, so it looked like nothing happened.

Comment: Same here :) Using SASS and set the font color with a config variable. Apparently form fields used the same var and I was doing a white text on black bg kind of page so form fields became white text on white bg.

Answer (score 5):

I have read all the answers above, and some directed me to the problem, but not to the solution for the problem.

The root cause of the problem is `disableSelection()`. It is causing all the problems, but removing it is not a solution, as (at least in 2016 or slightly before), on **touch-screen devices**, you "have" to use this if you want to be able to move objects with jQuery.

The solution was to leave the `disableSelection()` to the sortable element, but also add a binding action just above:

```
 $('#your_selector_id form').bind('mousedown.ui-disableSelection selectstart.ui-disableSelection', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
 })
```

The `form` in the jQuery element is just  to stop propagation on the form, as you might need propagation on some elements.

Comment: Thanks, there are alot of ppl have +1 above your comment.... but your comments is the only solution for my case.
It was I am using draggable control with input box inside of type number.
Thanks again :)

Comment: Some adjustments on the element and Voilà! Thanks ! I'm also using SORTABLE.

Answer (score 5):

This can occur in bootstrap if you do not place your columns inside a `<div class ='row'>`. The column floats are not cleared and you could get the next column overlying the previous, hence clicks wont hit the dom elements where you expect.

Answer (score 4):

If you are faced this problem while using canvas with DOM on mobile devices, the answer of `Ashwin G` worked for me perfectly, but I did it through javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("myinputfield");
element.onclick = element.select();
```

After, everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: This worked for me, in combination with Modernizr to target just touch devices (although I used `focus()`, as I didn't want the actual text to be selected if it was already populated).

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue - could not figure out what was the reason, but I fixed it using following code. Somehow it could not focus only the blank inputs:

```
$('input').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "") {
            this.select();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

### For Anyone Using Electron

For anyone having this issue with Electron specifically, the problem for me was using `alert` before selecting the input fields. Apparently `alert` and `confirm` aren't entirely supported by Electron, and therefore can mess up input fields. If you'd still like to use them, refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38859135/12293837

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because of this code:

```
$("#table tbody tr td:first-child").bind("mousedown", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('draggable');
});
```

I resolved it by removing

> e.preventDefault();

New code:

```
$("#table tbody tr td:first-child").bind("mousedown", function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('draggable');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is looking for this answer, we had a similar problem and solved it by changing the z-index of the input tags.  Apparently some other divs had extended too far and were overlapping the input boxes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for over 6 months, it may be the same issue. Main symptom is that you can't move the cursor or select text in text inputs, only the arrow keys allow you to move around in the input field. Very annoying problem, especially for textarea input fields. I have this html that gets populated with 1 out of 100s of forms via Javascript:

```
<div class="dialog" id="alert" draggable="true">
    <div id="head" class="dialog_head">
        <img id='icon' src='images/icon.png' height=20 width=20><img id='icon_name' src='images/icon_name.png' height=15><img id='alert_close_button' class='close_button' src='images/close.png'>
    </div>
    <div id="type" class="type"></div>
    <div class='scroll_div'>
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        <div id="msg" class="msg"></div>
        <div id="form" class="form"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Apparently 6 months ago I had tried to make the popup draggable and failed, breaking text inputs at the same time. Once I removed  draggable="true" it works again!

Comment: More information on `draggable="true"` on a containing div: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10375756/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **JQuery UI** and **Bootstrap** so I faced this issue and I think it is a conflict between the two as in normal case the textarea or the input filed is editable by nature but I made this solution after testing all the above answers but none solve the **cross browser support for all major browsers**, but I solved it and I like to share my solution you can use it on input text and textarea

***(Tested on Desktop: IE (All Versions), Chrome, Safari, Windows Edge, Firefox, Visual Studio Cordova Ripple Viewer on Windows & Visual Studio Cordova Windows 10 Store App)***

***(Tested on Mobile: Chrome, Firefox, Android Internet Browser & Visual Studio Cordova App on Android & Visual Studio Cordova Windows 8 + 8.1 + 10 Phone App)***

***This is the HTML Code:***

```
<textarea contenteditable id="textarea"></textarea>
```

**This is The CSS Code:**

```
textarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text !important;
    -khtml-user-select: text !important;
    -moz-user-select: text !important;
    -ms-user-select: text !important;
    user-select: text !important;
    /*to make sure that background color and text color is not the same (from the answers above)*/
    background-color:#fff !important;
    color:#733E27 !important;
 }
```

**This Is The JQuery Code On Document Ready**

```
$("textarea").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("textarea").focus();
            //add this if you are using JQuery UI (From The Solutions Above)
            $("textarea").enableSelection();
            var val = $("textarea").val();
            if (val.charAt(val.length-1) !== " " && val.length !== 1) {
                alert(val.length);
                val += " ";
            }
            $("textarea").val(val);
        }, 0);
    });

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1) {
        //alert('Its Safari or chrome');
        $("textarea").onfocus(function(e) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                var end;
                if ($("textarea").val === "") {
                    end = 0;
                } else {
                    end = $("textarea").val.length;
                }
                if ($("textarea").setSelectionRange) {
                    var range = document.getElementById('textarea').createTextRange();
                    if (range) {
                        setTimeout(range, 0, [end, end]);
                    } else { // IE style
                        var aRange = document.getElementById('textarea').createTextRange();
                        aRange.collapse(true);
                        aRange.moveEnd('character', end);
                        aRange.moveStart('character', end);
                        aRange.select();
                    }
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }, 0);
        });
    }
```

You can test it on my web application at [www.gahwehsada.com](http://www.gahwehsada.com/)

Comment: The question, does not involve bootstrap.
just sayin

Comment: I see but I mentioned that because there is no reason why a text area would not be editable unless there is a conflict in frameworks (and off course if no read only option is set)

Answer (score 2):

Its worth adding that having the property `pointer-events:none` on your input label will also produce this unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because of invalid `for attribute` in the label attribute

```
<input type="text" id="your_name" name="your_name">
<label for="your_name">Your Name</label>

<input type="text" id="your_email" name="your_name">
<label for="your_name">Your Name</label>
```

I have tried to update the `for attribute` in the second label to `your_email` instead of `your_name` and its works for me

```
<label for="your_email">Your Name</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
and nope, they don't have attributes: disabled="disabled" or readonly ;-)
```

Is this through viewing your html, the source code of the page, or the DOM?

If you inspect the DOM with Chrome or Firefox, then you will be able to see any attributes added to the input fields through javasript, or even an overlaying div

Answer (score 1):

I just found another possible reason for this issue, some input textboxes were missing the closing "/", so i had `<input ...>` when the correct form is `<input ... />`. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was Bootstrap popup in opened state.
Text input was in another calendar popup on top of Bootstrap one, input got its focus back after removing `tabindex="-1"` attribute from Bootstrap modal.

Comment: Did it not caused behavior issues after removing tabindex from bootstrap modal?

Answer (score 1):

***iPhone6 chrome***

Problem for me  was placing the input field inside `<label>` and `<p>`

like this :

```
<label>
  <p>
     <input/>
  </p>
</label>
```

I changed them to

```
<div>
  <div>
     <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it works for me .

*After check this answer, Please check other answers in this page, this issue may have different reasons*

Answer (score 0):

This will also happen anytime a div ends up positioned over controls in another div; like using bootstrap for layout, and having a "col-lg-4" followed by a "col-lg=8" misspelling... the right orphaned/misnamed div covers the left, and captures the mouse events. Easy to blow by that misspelling, - and = next to each other on keyboard.  So, pays to examine with inspector and look for 'surprises' to uncover these wild divs.

Is there an unseen window covering the controls and blocking events, and how can that happen?  Turns out, fatfingering = for - with bootstrap classnames is one way...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I eventually figured it out by inspecting the element and the element I thought I had selected was different element. When I did that I found there was a hidden element that had z-index of 9999, once I fixed that my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

the problem for me was that I was using  `class="modal fade"`, I changed it for  `class="modal hide"`. That solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction concerning Bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tore my hair for hours trying all sorts of solutions. Turned out to be an unclosed **a** tag.Try validate your HTML code, solution could be an unclosed tag causing issues

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using Bootstrap + contact form 7.
I for some reason I put the label as the container of the form and that was the issue for not being selectable on mobile.

```
<label>
    <contact form>...</contact form>
</label>
```

Seemed to break all inputs except the first input and the submit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the fix was to remove the placeholders and I changed the design of the form to use labels instead of placeholders...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue caused by a sort of overlap of a `div` element with a bootstrap `class ="row"` over a "brother" `div` element with the `class="col"`, the first hid the focus of the second `div` element.

I solved taking outer the `div row` element from that level of the divs' tree and so rebalancing bootstrap logical hierarchy based on the `row` and `col` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue just now in React.

I figured out that in the Router, Route. We cannot do this as it causes this issue of closing the mobile keyboard.

```
<Route 
 path = "some-path"
 component = {props => <MyComponent />}
 />
```

Make sure and use the render instead in this situation

```
<Route 
 path = "some-path"
 render = {props => <MyComponent />}
 />
```

Hope this helps someone

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dead thread, but for anyone happen to stumble into this problem the problem I hope that helps.

## The problem

When on Firefox for some reason whenever re-enabling a fieldset some inputs under it would be "broken", which means that I could click on them but not edit them, though if I tried to edit via script (doing things like `input.value = "hello"`) it would work, but still they couldn't be editable.

The code I had was like this:

```js
function enable_form() {
  let form = document.querySelector("#form1");
  form.querySelector("fieldset").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
Note: works only on firefox, and it "breaks" one (or more) random inputs

<form id="form1">
  <fieldset disabled>
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2">
    <input type="text" name="input3" id="input3">
    <input type="text" name="input4" id="input4">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<button onclick="enable_form()">enable form</button>
```

## Why this happens

This happens because apparently Firefox for some reason saves the "disabled" attribute of all inputs under a form (input1, input2, etc.) to be used whenever reloading the page (to avoid recompiling everything) because of the [autocomplete tag attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete).

And all inputs since they're not *directly* disabled (by putting "disabled" in the input tag) Firefox tries to inherit this state from the closest parent (in this case the fieldset), and for some reason sometimes for some input it won't recalculate correctly the value of the disabled flag and thus it appears enabled but actually it's not.

## How to solve

The fastest solution is to manually enable or disable all inputs under a script, for example by doing
`form_element.querySelectorAll("input, select").disabled = false` or true, depends on what you're doing.