# Replace 'Prompt' in on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

How to replace the function of javascript `prompt` in electron?

Can someone give me an example?

I tried to use the function `prompt`, but got an error:

> Uncaught Error: prompt() is and will not be supported.

Comment: I'm guessing a framework that lets you create cross-platform apps, based on Node.js, doesn't neccessarely support browser methods, like alert, prompt etc. for quite obvious reasons, there's no browser to display it in.

Comment: @adeneo Electron is based on Chromium in every platform, so yes there's a browser and it is always the same :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`prompt`, `confirm` and `alert` are functions which blocks the execution thread of the script until a user input and that's the reason electron team didn't supported it. Instead you can use some third party package for the same reason.

Here are some packages which provides this functionality in async way

https://www.npmjs.com/package/smalltalk

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vex-js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogs

Comment: I am able to call `alert` and `confirm`. Is that not expected?

Comment: The answer lies in the electron file window-setup.js. `window.alert` and `window.confirm` have implementations, but `window.prompt` throws an exception.

Comment: smalltalk does not work with electron out of the box!

Answer (score 6):

My answer is a little late but maybe still helpful for others.

Since the Electron team does not want to implement the `prompt()` behavior themselves, I developed this solution: [electron-osx-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-osx-prompt).
It provides a Promise-based way to get some simple user input and adapts to the macOS styling.

```
// From renderer or main process, doesn't matter
const userPrompt = require('electron-osx-prompt');

const icon = __dirname + '/icon.png';

userPrompt('Label text', 'Placeholder text', icon)
  .then(input => {
    console.log(input);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: I used this and found for Electron 5.x+, you need to edit the index.js file and add 

webPreferences { nodeIntegration: true } 

in the BrowserWindow creation process.