# Prompt an input box in atom electron?

Tags: javascript, input, electron, prompt

I am very new (couple of days) to HTML/JAVASCRIPT etc and I have started learning UI design with electron. I know how to create **buttons** and can handle what they do when **pressed**.

What I could not find is a way to input something in electron js.

For example I want an input field where I will **type a number** and a **button next to it**, that when **clicked** should **save this** **number** for other uses. In normal **Javascript on a browser** I know how to do this, in fact a simple "**prompt**" can also serve my purpose, but unfortunately even **prompt doesn't work on electron** ! What is the simplest way to achieve what I am trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt on Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858879/prompt-on-electron)

Comment: And as is stated in that duplicate, Electron is built upon Node.JS; there's no **browser** for you to able to trigger things like `prompt()`. If you're looking for that sort of behaviour, and **insist** on using frameworks like Electron, things are going to get complicated with the requirement of additional Node.JS packages.

Comment: It's not a duplicate as my question is not about "prompt" ! It's about input method in general. I can't believe there is not even a fixed input box field where data can be typed in and adjacent button clicked to insert it ! If there is no input method than electron seems pretty useless.