# why is my eventlistener not working in electron

Tags: events, electron

I am trying to learn Electron js. 
I have a very simple HTML in my index.html

```
  <!doctyp html> 

   ... all the other normal declarations ...

  <button class="alert">alert</button>
  <script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('.alert');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => { alert('alerting');}) 
  </script>
```

For some reason this does not work in Electron. When I ran this code in  any other web browser it worked fine. what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858879/replace-prompt-in-on-electron - `alert` is not supported in Electron because it blocks execution flow. Use Electrons built in dialog to achieve a similar, non-blocking effect.

Comment: @somethinghere That is at most half of the truth. Just read all the text and comment on the linked answer. We *can* call `window.alert` because electron provides an implementation for that. It's just `window.prompt` that does not work and where we need a custom implementation, like `electron-dialog`.

Comment: when I just wrote in my script tag ``` <script>alert("alerting");</script>```. It showed an alert, but when using an event listener it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. 
In my meta tags I had the following tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *" />
```

I changed it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
```

and now it works.

Thank for the help.