# vuetify electron reset form

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuetify.js, electron-vue

i'm developing an app with vue, vuetify and electron. I have a form that i can submit, but once submitted,after the reset i can't compile it again, i have all input blank, if i click on an input they appear as active, but can't write inside.
i tried many solutions found over the internet, but with no success.
the form is inside a v-dialog, i reset with

```
   this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
   this.$refs.form.reset()
```

or i tried also

```
this.$refs.form.reset()
this.dataForm = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
```

but the behaviour is always the same

someone could help me please?
thank you

Comment: Can you post a sandbox demonstrating the error?

Comment: with vue and vuetify no problem, but how can i make it work with electron?

Comment: sorry, reading another discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38859135/8927434 the "prompt, confirm and alert are functions which blocks the execution thread of the script until a user input and that's the reason electron team didn't supported it. " and i showed an alert at the catch event, so it freezes the inputs