# cannot select text, cannot click <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I create a div on a function

```
function formatdata() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = 'inTable';
  div.innerHTML = "<label>Cannot Select</label><input type='text' value='' style='z-index:1300;!important'>";
  return div;
}

$('#data-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = tabel.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    var data = tabel.row(this).data();
    row.child(formatdata(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

I cannot select the label, cannot focus on input field with cursor, but use tab key it can focus, i think, its about z-index of this div is lower than parent element, I just create script to get z-index

```
$(document.body).click(function() {
  var zind = $(this).css('z-index');
  alert(zin);
});
```

When i clicked the div, parent of div its say "auto", in chrome i check developer tools -> element , but i don't know where is the problem.

Anyone can guide me to know where is the problem?

Comment: Have you appended the div into the DOM? You have to in order to be able to click or focus it!

Comment: `style='z-index:1300;!important'` --> `z-index` won't apply if the element is *not positioned* (positioned = `fixed`, `absolute`, `relative`, `sticky` - **not** `static`), your `!important` declaration should *precede* the semi-colon terminations (e.g: `z-index:1300 !important;`), if you use an *inline-style* with the `!important` declaration you will not be able to *over-qualify* this rule with external styles *unless* you use an `id` selector (which carries more **weight**) and another `!important` declaration.

Comment: Good point but if he didn't do that how can he try to select or click if there is nothing to see? :D As I understand it the elements are visible in the browser, no?

Comment: You know, the only thing we really need to see here is the rendered html and the styles applicable to it (not *all* your markup, just *enough* to pass as a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example*) - your question, as it is now, doesn't actually *demonstrate or reproduce* the problem. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, thanks, i tried it, but i cannot give simple explanation

Comment: @onyseven that's ok Ony, consider how you can make this happen, this will surely improve the question. Until then, the question is *off topic* since the issue cannot be demonstrated or reproduced - voting to close.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, what i ve to do, modified my question or i create a new question?

Comment: Finnaly, i use this [html input does not get focus when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14686137/2710052)

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the created div into the body

```js
function formatdata() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = 'inTable';
  div.innerHTML = "<label>Cannot Select</label><input type='text' value='' style='z-index:1300;!important'>";
  return div;
}


document.body.appendChild(formatdata());
```

Comment: i've update myquestion, actually this is on a function

Comment: sorry i've update myquestion again,  actually i use this script before and no problem with my old website template, and  when i use on new website template, and the problem is come