# Cannot click/focus into textbox, due to onmousedown="return false;"

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, textbox

I have put some search and email registration textboxes into a page and I can't click on the field to focus on it and enter text.

After some troubleshooting I discovered that the reason for this, is the main div, that includes the content. It has these rules:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" onmousedown="return false;" onselectstart="return false;">
```

These restrictions were put there for discouraging stealing content. This prevents the user from focusing on the text-fields.

What would be the best way to keep the restriction for the main div, yet allow the user to click on the textboxes? Maybe just the `onselectstart` is enough to prevent copy/paste and I can delete the `onmousedown` parameter?

You can see the problem in [this page](http://www.roulette30.com/about)

Comment: Try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of linking to that page. Also, why not just try removing the onmousedown parameter? Have you?

Comment: Yes, I have and it solves the problem. I just wonder if it offers added benefit in discouraging copy/paste or if 'onselectstart' is enough.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem 
was solved, especially if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not sure why the `onmousedown="return false;"` was there (I'm a newbie) I decided to leave it there and just add some code around the text-boxes, that would allow the user to click/focus on them.

I found the answer in an [older related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724749/html-input-fields-does-not-get-focus-when-clicked). That question had received 24 different answers, but the one that I found the simplest of all and fully understood how to implement, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14686137/5303256):

> Use the `onclick="this.select()"` attribute for the input tag.

This way we keep the restrictions for the main div, but we allow clicking in the input field. Tested and it works.